# AppleScript Assistive Error 1719 when using System Events "click"

Tags: macos, applescript, accessibility

I'm starting to loose the plot here. I have an AppleScript application that needs to use the click command for system events. When run in Script Editor, it works perfectly. When exported as an application and run, it first will prompt for accessibility access, which i grant. Then it will fail with the error:

"appname is not allowed assistive access. System Events got an error: appname is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)."

I've seen that this is a common issue when looking around forums, however I've tried almost every suggested fix to no avail. This is what I've tried:

- Removing and re-adding the item in Settings>Privacy&Security>Accessibility list, "-" on the app then re-add it manually
- Every varition under the sun of the above including closing Settings inbetween each step, and restarting in between each step
- I've added iTerm (the target app) to the same list in settings as suggested in another post here
- I've done the above and manually added the script to the list, and also automatically (i.e. removed it, rebooted, re-run the app and got it to add via the prompt, toggled the entry in the list then tried to re-run)

Below is my testing subscript which I've been using to confirm my assumption that the click command was the only problem - others have had issues with variables writing locally and therefore changing the application signature that macos has registered in the list and treating it as a new application. Mine does not do this - it doesn't change the file details, and I don't get a new prompt each time asking for access - just one that says it is denied.

```html
set runQuit to true
set runGetBranch to true
set runiTerm to true
set runVSCode to true
set runBrowser to true

set branchName to "dev"
set clickTest to true
set keyTest to false

------------------------------------------------------------------
--Quit Apps                                     --
------------------------------------------------------------------
--Quit VS Code
if runQuit then
    tell application "Visual Studio Code"
        quit
    end tell
    tell application "iTerm"
        quit
    end tell
end if

delay 2

------------------------------------------------------------------
--Get Branch Number                             --
------------------------------------------------------------------
if runGetBranch then
    set branchNameResponse to display dialog "What branch are you checking out?" default answer "ABC-" with icon note buttons {"Cancel", "dev", "Continue"} default button "Continue"
    
    if (button returned of branchNameResponse is "dev") then
        set branchName to "dev"
    else if (button returned of branchNameResponse is "Continue") then
        set branchName to text returned of branchNameResponse
    else --Cancel
        error number -128 --user canceled script
    end if
end if

set clickTestResponse to display dialog "Clicking Off? (testing)" buttons {"Off", "On", "KeyCode"} default button "On"

if button returned of clickTestResponse is "Off" then
    set clickTest to false
end if

if button returned of clickTestResponse is "KeyCode" then
    set keyTest to true
    set clickTest to false
end if

------------------------------------------------------------------
--Start iTerm                                       --
------------------------------------------------------------------
if runiTerm then
    tell application "iTerm" to activate
    
    --Close the initial terminal 3 times (incase default layout was already opened)
    repeat 5 times
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "iTerm2"
                tell menu bar item "Shell" of menu bar 1
                    if clickTest is true then click
                    if keyTest is true then key code 76
                    tell menu item "Close" of menu 1
                        if clickTest is true then click
                        if keyTest is true then key code 76
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end repeat
    
    --Open default Layout
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "iTerm2"
            tell menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
                if clickTest is true then click
                if keyTest is true then key code 76
                tell menu item "Restore Window Arrangement" of menu 1
                    if clickTest is true then click
                    if keyTest is true then key code 76
                    if clickTest is true then click menu item "Default" of menu 1
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    
end if
```

Bascially it will quit VS and iterm, as the user for some input (a branch to checkout and my test question to switch between using the click and the key code for return to interact with the menu of iterm), then close iterms windows and open the default layout. I've tried doing this all by keyboard shortcuts and unfortunately cannot get it to trigger the correct menu options so have resorted to clicking.

```html
if clickTest is true then click <-- fails
if keyTest is true then key code 76 <-- succeeds, but has issues elsewhere it's used in the script so I've had to put it aside for now.
```

If anyone has come across this issue before